# ACF Pro - Field showing up in backend, but it's not saving (disappear on refresh)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a website with more than 15 ACF groups. On one of them, there's a repeater and the last of 6 fields is a URL (I tried switching it to Text, same result). I see the field on my page where I use it as a block (Gutenberg). I can enter a value, and it "saves"... Or so I think. If I refresh the page, it's not there anymore (the field is empty).

Now, I went on and switched to the Visual Editor - Code view, and... it's not there. Nothing. I'm wondering: why is it showing when I'm in Classic View, but not on code view... clearly, if it's not there, it ain't saving!

After that, I added the code myself and what do I see: **it's there, and saving, and still there.**

To add the code myself is a big No-No because I'm building a site for a client... There must be a solution or a known patch...

*(NB: I do not have any code to display since it's kindof in the backend... and not really code-ish related)*

Answer (score 2):

Possible cause: Field name missing or duplicated

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76272395/7733418:
If a Field name is either missing or duplicated (if two or more fields have the same name), it will cause update issues. In ACF, "Field Names" act as IDs so they should exist and be unique.

Comment: a) there is no answer or comment by desertnaut here b) your post is not an answer either c) generally if you do not answer according to [answer] please do not click "Post Your Answer" button d) please take the [tour] again, you seem to have missed at least this important concept e) you may eitherh edit the same answer desertnaut did and improve it by your more explicit and more detailed phrasing or [edit] this post and turn it into an actual answer, but be sure to mention what you base yours on, via link from "Share" there

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: I did my best to turn this into an answer, away from what gave mostly an impression of misusing an answer post for a comment to say thanks. I ironed out a few misunderstandings you had concerning what an answer is, how to refer to something and unhelpfully noisy formatting. I think you need to review that you state thast the post you refer to already mentions what you contribute. You do well in noting that something was already here, but I do not really see it. I nevertheless am confident that I identified correctly which post you mean (because I can see deleted ones...). So please review.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it by erasing the files in the /theme-name/acf-json/fr/ directory. It happens to me once in a while. Probably because we are using WPML (that explains the /fr/) and the firm who made the website made all fields translatable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Increase your max input vars by editing (or creating) the .user.ini file in the web root. By default the max input vars is only 1,000.

```
max_input_vars = 2000
```

You might want to review all of these settings if you have very large amounts of text.

```
memory_limit = 128M
max_input_vars = 2000
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 120
```

Then confirm your changes take affect with a php info file.

Answer (score 0):

Can be reason 1: ACF fields not saving

I also had problem where the custom fields were not getting saved in the backend editor.

You should do a backup of the website before you try this. If you don't know how to do (save wp-content folder, export database), I recommend a free plugin called "All-in-One Migration" to do the backup.

My solution for ACF fields not getting saved:

1. Duplicate the field group in the ACF page. To do so go to the field group page of the acf plugin, hover the field group name, there should now be a link called "Duplicate".
2. After duplicating you delete the "old" field group. You can now name the new field group the way it was called.
3. You will notice that all the field names are still the same, so it will work if you got the fields echoed in the template files of the website. Do only now have new "keys" for the fields in the database.
4. Try to save the fields in the backend editor now, the problem with not saving fields should be solved.

This helped me when I deployed a website to another server. Sometimes the keys must be re-defined by using this duplicate method.

---

Can be reason 2: saving process can not complete

Edit the php.ini file on your webserver or contact the host to do so and increase  max_input_vars and max_execution_time.
Maybe there are too many fields and values so there are more than the maximum allowed input vars. Or the saving process is taking too long because of lots of fields, so the maximum execution time is reached, saving process cannot run to the end of all fields.

Comment: Thanks for that, it did not work tho. I also discovered that if I change the fields order, it's the last one that is not saving. So now, I'm guessing the issue is the saving space on the server or the DB. Could it be?

Comment: It can have another reason, do you have access to the php.ini on the webserver?  maybe you have to increase max_input_vars or execution time. sounds like that could be the issue. so the saving the form would not complete because input vars are too much or saving process is taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete the ACF group and recreate it in order to get the saving of data changes working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.
I went back to my Field Group, it turns out my repeater did not have a name nor a key...

I filled them, now it works as it should.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34403059)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several of the suggested solutions. The only thing that helped was deleting the field data in the wp-postmeta table. I recommend making a backup first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35719736)